# Matrix differentiation

Tags: matrix, calculus, differentiation

I am reviewing basic matrix differentiation rules and came across 2 contradicting references.  Which one is correct?  In both 'a' is a constant vector and hence partial and regular derivatives would need to be the same.  Given that we might use these rules to simplify complex derivatives,  I believe only one of the below can be correct - otherwise, dimensional analysis would go for a toss.

https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs5240/lecture/matrix-differentiation.pdf
says

[image]

Where as the cook book at 
https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf says

[image]

Which is the right one (should it transpose a or not transpose?)

-Rajesh

Comment: There is no commonly agreed standard here, and it - as you have seen - depends on the author. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions). If you want to know more, I'd suggest you ask on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: cool.  that was helpful.  So while I replace rules into complex derivatives, as long as I follow one of the system - I should be fine?.  Is that what you are saying?  Thanks again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.